# Authentication request returned unexpected result 404

Tags: gmail-api

Following is a code to get google contacts.
It was working fine but since few days I m getting exception of "Authentication request returned unexpected result: 404".

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Extensions;

private void FetchContactList()
{
     List<string> lstContacts = new List<string>();
     RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new RequestSettings("my application", "abc@gmail.com", "XXXXXX");
     rsLoginInfo.AutoPaging = true;

     ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(rsLoginInfo);
     Feed<contact> feedContacts = cRequest.GetContacts();
    foreach (Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries)
    {
        // Looping to read email addresses
         foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails)
        {
             lstContacts.Add(emailId.Address);
        }
    }
   GridView1.DataSource = lstContacts;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Is google change something from their side?
Please suggest me way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your current api with google api to version 3 and then make changes to the code according. Probably this may be the reason for the error.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries

i further suggest you use **oauth2.0** for authentication as per the current requirements of your application and if you are using the older version of the api then you must use **oauth2.0**

Here is the link for **oauth2.0** support: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize

though this is basically for spreadsheets but you can see how it is and working and change it to the requirements of your gmail api

Comment: Thank you.
Can you please suggest me link which contain example of Import Contact using oauth2.0 support?

Comment: this is the link on how to use the **oauth2.0** with gmail api  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/